# Understanding of Laplacian Operator

Tags: vector-analysis, laplacian

My understanding of this topic is that the Laplacian operator can be applied to both scalar fields as well as vector fields. The formula

$$\nabla^2  \equiv \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial z^2}$$
 works for either a scalar or a vector.

1) Is it true that Laplacian can be applied to vectors(which I think is a yes)?

2) If yes,then just as we call the Laplacian of a scalar as "Divergence of a gradient",can we also call Laplacian of a vector field as "Gradient of Divergence"?`

(I am new to text editors so please if someone could edit it correctly)

PS:I did some research online but it rather confuses me as to whether or not Laplacian is applicable to a vector.

Comment: Have you checked the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Laplacian) article?

Comment: @ares thanks,doubt is cleared.Not grad of divergence only but with an extra term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said the laplacian works for both scalar and vector.
That being said 
-scalar laplacian=div(grad)
-vector laplacian=grad(div) -curl(curl)
that means that vector laplacian is not really grad(div) but grad(div) minus curl of curl.

Comment: Thanks for that!